Setting timeFrom equal to a specific time of the current day in Grafana
I would like my panel to be able to grab data from 6am to now each day. Using Grafana with Elasticsearch... still very new to it too.
I currently have "timeFrom": "now/d", which gives me the data from the start of the day. However, there seems to be no way to just do "timeFrom": "now/d+6h", to have it start from 6am. Is there a different solution that I am overlooking in the UI?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
